# Azure Functions with CVS doco/guidance

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I would like to connect Azure Functions to a repository where on each master push functions would be redeployed along with artifacts (`Project.json`, `function.json`, etc). Is there anything already in place? If not, anything planned?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sean,

Since Azure Functions sits on top of App Service/Web Apps, this is a fully supported scenario and you can find detailed information on the deployment process [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-deploy/#continuousdeployment)

I also have deployment scripts you can use with your function to make sure your packages are properly restored on deployment [here](https://github.com/fabiocav/webjobs-scripts-samples) (you can find more information about how to use the script [here](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Custom-Deployment-Script))

Hope this helps!